# Angular unit testing TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, frontend, karma-jasmine

I'm creating starter kit template with auth and a example with CRUD (https://github.com/fransyozef/basic-login-angular)

Now I'm new with unit testing and i'm trying to get atleast get the testing running that the components are created. But I'm getting stuck with

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

I think the error comes from

```
  resolveRoute() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.getItem();
      } else {
        this.handleItemNotFound();
      }
     });
  }
```

in the file https://github.com/fransyozef/basic-login-angular/blob/master/src/app/items/item-edit/item-edit.component.ts

Right now I have the testfile :
https://github.com/fransyozef/basic-login-angular/blob/master/src/app/items/item-edit/item-edit.component.spec.ts

Can somebody give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock your routing strategy. As i can see you use a `routingModule` inside your `TestBed imports`. Assume that your *own* `routingModule` only provide your own routes and will not be able to mock/spy another routes. So I will encourage you to adjust first your `Test helper routes` inside `test.helper.ts`

```
export const TestRoutingImports = [
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  RouterTestingModule, // <-- Use RouterTestingModule instead
];
```

> The(RouterTestingModule) modules sets up the router to be used for testing. It provides spy implementations of Location, LocationStrategy, and NgModuleFactoryLoader.

**RouterTestingModule provide mocks, RouterModule not.**

The second thing you should do is to remove your `provide` from the Testbed. It's here not necessary. I mean the following part:

```
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
     snapshot: { params: { id: 1 } }
  }
},
```

Remove this because this will be a Overriding of the components providers. In your case it's not needed.

I hope i could help you.

Comment: thanx!!! Will surely try it. If you have any good articles about this I would really like to know :)

Comment: You're welcome..Here a good article to learn more about unit testing in angular https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-testing-guide-a485b6cb1ef0